# Computing a Joint Density of 2 RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, density-function

Suppose $X,Y$ are discrete integer-valued random variables (possibly dependent), where $Y=0,1,$ or $2$.

I want to compute the joint probability $P(X>Y)$ given below:

$$\begin{matrix}
&X&0&1&2\\
Y&&\\
0&&p_{0,0}&p_{0,1}&p_{0,2}\\
1&&p_{1,0}&p_{1,1}&p_{1,2}\\
2&&p_{2,0}&p_{2,1}&p_{2,2}.\\
\end{matrix}$$

Here $$p_{i,j}=P(Y=i\cap X=j).$$

Now,

$$P(X>Y)=p_{0,1}+p_{0,2}+p_{1,2}.$$

If I have the pmfs, and cdfs for $X,Y$ how can they be used to evaluate the $p_{i,j}$'s; **what additional information is needed to compute the joint distribution?**

I've tried $p_{i,j}=P(X=i, Y=j)=P(X=i)P(Y=j\vert X=i)$, but I don't know how to compute the conditional probability since $X,Y$ have different distributions.

Comment: You only have distribution of individual random variables. So you can only calculate joint distribution if they are independent. If not , you need to have some more information. If random variables are independent, relations like $P(X>Y)$ can be written as $P(X-Y >0)$ where you can take a new random variable $Z = X - Y$, whose distribution is convolution of distributions of $X, Y$. In this way you can find the distribution of Z and then probabilities.

Comment: What additional information would be needed to compute the joint distribution?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no certain way to say it. But if you can find the conditional probability, lets say $P(Y|X)$, as a function of random variable $X$ that would help solve it. If you are dealing with practical problems always try to bring functions of random variables in such a form where all ca be assumed independent.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to get $P(X > Y)$ from the marginal probability distributions for $X$ and $Y$.

I don't think this can be done! Consider these two scenarios:

$$ \begin{matrix}
&X&0&1&2\\
Y&&\\
0&&\tfrac 1 3 & 0 & 0 \\
1&&0 & \tfrac 1 3 & 0 \\
2&&0 & 0 & \tfrac 1 3\\
\end{matrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\begin{matrix}
&X&0&1&2\\
Y&&\\
0&&\tfrac 1 9 & \tfrac 1 9 & \tfrac 1 9\\
1&&\tfrac 1 9 & \tfrac 1 9 & \tfrac 1 9\\
2&&\tfrac 1 9 & \tfrac 1 9 & \tfrac 1 9\\
\end{matrix}$$

In both cases, we have
$$ P(X = 0) = P(X = 1) = P(X = 2) = P(Y = 0) = P(Y = 1) = P(Y = 2) = \tfrac 1 3.$$
So the two cases cannot be distinguished from the marginal probability distributions alone. Intuitively, the problem is that the marginal distributions do not tell you anything about the extent to which the two random variables are correlated.

Anyway, in the first case we have $P(X > Y) = 0$, whereas in the second case we have $P(X > Y) = \frac 1 3$. So $P(X > Y)$ is not determined by the information you are given.

Comment: What additional information would be needed to compute $P(X>Y)$?

Comment: @IcedPalmer To be honest, I think you need a lot of information. Such as conditional probabilities. Perhaps covariances and other moments. However many things are required to enable you to solve a bunch of simultaneous equations to get $P(X > Y)$.